# Why doesn't the button hit the event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Why button doesn't hit the event ? I put a breakpoint, started with debugging but when I click it doesn't hit the event but other buttons does ? Why ?

I have also posted complete code in case you want to take a look at it.

event:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPostBack && Page.IsValid)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text))
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Fill the required fields !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                    return;
                }

                byte ID = Convert.ToByte(HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value);
                string ContractorTypeName = txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text;

                if (MngContractorTypes.UpdateContractorTypes(ID, ContractorTypeName))
                {
                    txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = "";
                    ShowContractorTypes();

                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Record updated successfully !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Green);
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Failed !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        finally
        {
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }

    }
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" ValidationGroup="0" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning"
                                            Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"   />
```

Complete code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="ajax-loading">
                <div></div>
            </div>

        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <center> 
                      <asp:Panel ID="ResultPanel" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                  </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-primary">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Add Contractor Type</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                                Contractor Type
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnFieldContractorTypeID" runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxContractorTypeName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                           <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="Clear()" class="btn btn-success" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddContractorType" ValidationGroup="0" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                            Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddContractorType_Click" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-warning"
                                            Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Visible="false" />

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel fadeIn">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-success">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Contractor Types</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Search
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtSearch" ValidationGroup="S"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Search" Style="margin-top: 25px" ValidationGroup="S" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewContractorTypes" OnRowEditing="grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractorTypeName" HeaderText="Contractor Type" />
                                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />


                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Contractors;

public partial class MainForms_ContractorTypes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx ResultLabel = new ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx();
    Contractors.ManageContractorTypes MngContractorTypes = new ManageContractorTypes();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx ResultLabel = new ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void btnAddContractorType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text))
            {
                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Fill the required fields !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                return;
            }

            string ContractorTypeName = txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text;

            if (MngContractorTypes.InsertContractorTypes(ContractorTypeName))
            {

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text= "";

                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Record inserted successfully !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Green);


            }
            else
            {

                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Account Already Exist !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
    }
    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "edit")
            {
                byte ContractorTypeID = Convert.ToByte(grdviewContractorTypes.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);

                //HFActID.Value = ID.ToString();

                btnAddContractorType.Visible = false;
                btnUpdate.Visible = true;

                DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeID(ContractorTypeID);
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = r["ContractorTypeName"].ToString();
                HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value = r["pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID"].ToString();
                //txtSearch.Text = "Testing...";
                //Response.Write("DONE");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(Convert.ToString(ex.Message));
        }
    }
    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to edit
    }
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text))
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Fill the required fields !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                    return;
                }

                byte ID = Convert.ToByte(HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value);
                string ContractorTypeName = txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text;

                if (MngContractorTypes.UpdateContractorTypes(ID, ContractorTypeName))
                {
                    txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = "";
                    ShowContractorTypes();

                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Record updated successfully !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Green);
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Failed !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                }
            }
        catch (Exception) { }

        finally
        {
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }

    }
    private void ShowContractorTypes()
    {

        grdviewContractorTypes.DataSource = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypes();
        grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();

    }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeName(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataSource = dt;
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                grdviewContractorTypes.EmptyDataText = "No Record Found";
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried and hit `btnUpdate_Click` multiple times with no problem.

Comment: not working, I tried another button with same code but not working

Comment: Try removing and readding `onClick` event.

Comment: Did that dude, not working

Comment: read my new post in which i described exact issue. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177661/why-all-buttons-stops-firing-events-when-i-click-edit?noredirect=1#comment52242127_32177661

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied this method from other page/application ?

If **yes** then it will not work.

You need to delete the event and event name assigned to the button then go to design view and go to button event properties go to onClick event double click next to it, it will generate event and it automatically assigns event name to the button.

If **No**,

Try to `Clean` your solution and then try once again.
Please refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e53aab69-75b9-434a-bde3-74ca0865c165/vs2010-how-to-clean-up-the-visual-stadio-unused-files?forum=vsdebug) article

Comment: Is there any validation error ?
To test, try removing ValidationGroup property and then test it once

Comment: plus it halts the other button too i.e. make them unclickable

Comment: I did, removed validation grp property but not working

Comment: add CausesValidation="false"  to the button tag

Comment: Is your button tag inside the form tag ?
If yes, then please add runat="server" to the form tag

Comment: I noticed one thing, when I click EDIT button then this happens otherwise if i don't click edit then it hits event but all buttons stops hitting event when i hit Edit

Comment: I think this code is the culprit 

 protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to edit
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the access modifier from protected to public, this will stop the method from being called depending on your class structure.

See here for more information on access modifiers: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx**

Comment: not working, I tried another button with same code but not working

Comment: Exactly where you put the break point? if it is inside the `if` statement, the condition `Page.IsValid` may be false and hence the code is not executing and not hitting the break point. place the break point on `'if` statement and try.

Comment: So the "btnAddContractorType" button does get called?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the AutoPostBack property of the Button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" ValidationGroup="0" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" AutoPostBack="true"   />
```

Comment: not working, I tried another button with same code but not working