# Why all buttons stops firing events when I click edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

In the page below I have a number of buttons, and a grid with an edit button.

All button events fire as they should the first time I load the page, but after I click the edit button in the grid all buttons stop firing their click events.

.aspx Code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/home/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContractorTypes.aspx.cs" Inherits="MainForms_ContractorTypes" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ResultLabel.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ResultLabel" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Clear() {
            location.reload(true);

        }
        function GetConfrim() {
            if (confirm("Are You Sure ?")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="ajax-loading">
                <div></div>
            </div>

        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <center> 
                      <asp:Panel ID="ResultPanel" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                  </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-primary">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Add Contractor Type</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                                Contractor Type
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnFieldContractorTypeID" runat="server" />
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxContractorTypeName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="Clear()" class="btn btn-success" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddContractorType" ValidationGroup="0" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                            Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddContractorType_Click" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdated" ValidationGroup="0" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                            Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdated_Click" />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel fadeIn">
                            <div class="panel-header bg-success">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Contractor Types</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-content">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Search
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtSearch" ValidationGroup="S"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Search" Style="margin-top: 25px" ValidationGroup="S" />
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewContractorTypes" OnRowEditing="grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractorTypeName" HeaderText="Contractor Type" />
                                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />


                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Contractors;

public partial class MainForms_ContractorTypes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx ResultLabel = new ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx();
    Contractors.ManageContractorTypes MngContractorTypes = new ManageContractorTypes();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx ResultLabel = new ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void btnAddContractorType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text))
            {
                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Fill the required fields !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                return;
            }

            string ContractorTypeName = txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text;

            if (MngContractorTypes.InsertContractorTypes(ContractorTypeName))
            {

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text= "";

                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Record inserted successfully !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Green);


            }
            else
            {

                ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Account Already Exist !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
    }
    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "edit")
            {
                byte ContractorTypeID = Convert.ToByte(grdviewContractorTypes.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);

                //HFActID.Value = ID.ToString();

                btnAddContractorType.Visible = false;
                btnUpdated.Visible = true;

                DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeID(ContractorTypeID);
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = r["ContractorTypeName"].ToString();
                HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value = r["pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID"].ToString();
                //txtSearch.Text = "Testing...";
                //Response.Write("DONE");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(Convert.ToString(ex.Message));
        }
    }
    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        // code to edit

    }

    private void ShowContractorTypes()
    {

        grdviewContractorTypes.DataSource = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypes();
        grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();

    }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeName(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataSource = dt;
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                grdviewContractorTypes.EmptyDataText = "No Record Found";
                grdviewContractorTypes.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    protected void btnUpdated_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsPostBack && Page.IsValid)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text))
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Fill the required fields !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                    return;
                }

                byte ID = Convert.ToByte(HdnFieldContractorTypeID.Value);
                string ContractorTypeName = txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text;

                if (MngContractorTypes.UpdateContractorTypes(ID, ContractorTypeName))
                {
                    txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = "";
                    ShowContractorTypes();

                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Record updated successfully !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Green);
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Failed !", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception) { }

        finally
        {
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not following. Would you mind explaining the steps you do when it works and when it doesn't work? What are "the other buttons" you are talking about? I only see the code for the edit button..

Comment: @Patrick sir check the updated code now

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation. As it is now it is unbearable.

Comment: Why are you using the OnRowEditing event if you only have an empty event handler? Can't you just remove it?

Comment: Where are the other buttons located in relation to the grid? Please update the code where you have the HTML in one code snippet, and your c# code in another snippet.

Comment: Sir, If I don't use OnRowEditing then it doesn't fire the OnRowCommandEvent

Comment: @Patrick I have used all the code, check now

Comment: @Patrick: It has wasted 2 days of mine but still no luck, please help if u can

Comment: I haven't used ASP.NET WebForms in about 3 years because of issues similar to the one you are experiencing now. ASP.NET MVC is so much simpler in this regard.. The only reason I can think of is if you are using dynamic controls and adding them in code (as you are doing in the finally block above) and not readding them on postback. The view needs to be rebuilt exactly the same as when you sent the page to the client the first time in order for events to work correctly.